# How to convert template classes?

Tags: c++, templates, virtual

I have following example:

```
struct Wrapper
{
    virtual ~Wrapper()
    {
    }

    template <typename U>
    WrapperT<U> * clone()
    {
        return new WrapperT<U>(value); //will not work, because value is not known here
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct WrapperT : Wrapper
{
    explicit WrapperT(T v)
    {
        value = v;
    }

    T value;
};
```

and I want something like this:

```
Wrapper *t = new WrapperT<int>(1);
WrapperT<double> *t2 = t->clone<double>();
```

I know virtual templates are not available. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you want to happen when someone does `t->clone<foo*>()` on the next line? (Where `foo` is a completely unrelated type)

Comment: What about a converting construtor `template<typename U> explicit WrapperT(const WrapperT<U>&);`?

Comment: @jrok: That constructor would not know the real type. He wants to convert from a pointer to the base to the derived type.

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach is defining a visitor pattern, but the cost of implementing the visitor might be large if you want to support many different wrapped types (i.e. if it is not just a small subset).

Another problem you would get is that the conversions would be (have to be) dynamically dispatched, so they can fail at runtime and you would have to provide mechanisms to detect that and act on that then (exceptions come to mind). Nothing horrible...

Comment: I thing this pattern is not suitable for my app. I want to convert all possible types that are supported by the compiler.

Comment: @SteffenRoeber: The problem is that you are loosing the type information when the element you pass around is the base type. To be able to recover that type information you need to use dynamic dispatch at runtime, but fully *generic* solutions require templates and static dispatch (i.e. let the compiler generate the piece of code that you need). You will need to find a different design.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I propose is using a "neutral type" to make dynamically (as David Rodríguez - dribeas noted) the type conversion.

Advantage:

- The solution is generic: you don't need to so any special thing when using a new type.

As drawbacks

- Not good for performance.
- Requires the insertion and extraction stream operators to be defined.

The code:

```
struct Wrapper
{
    // get the "neutral type" value
    virtual string getValue() const = 0;

    template <typename U> Wrapper* clone() const;
};

template <typename T>
struct WrapperT: Wrapper
{
    explicit WrapperT(T v):  value(v)
    {
    }

    virtual string getValue() const 
    {
        // use streams to conversion to neutral value, but 
        // other better method would be suitable
        ostringstream   strm;
        strm << value;
        return strm.str();
    }

    T value;
};

template <typename U> Wrapper* Wrapper::clone() const {
    U   value;
    istringstream   strm(getValue());
    strm >> value;

    return new WrapperT<U>(value);
}
```

**EDIT:**

For a better performance solution, if only using numeric type, we can change `string` by a `long double` as "neutral type":

```
template <typename T>
double long WrapperT<T>::getValue() const 
{
    return value;
}

template <typename U> Wrapper* Wrapper::clone() const {
    return new WrapperT<U>(getValue());
}
```

Do we want to avoid integral to floating point conversions when using only integral type? In that case, the solution will be a bit more complex:

- create two `getValue()` virtual functions, one for integral and other one for floating point,
- in `clone()` function select the desired `getValue()` function depending on `U` template parameter type (target type).

Comment: I Need a high performance solution. Streaming is no choice I think.

Comment: I read something about trampoline functions. But if they are suitable here I dont know.

Comment: @SteffenRoeber: You can create your own conversion function. If you are always using numeric types, you could convert to floating point type (`double` or `long double`) as neutral type.

Comment: I#m not only using numerics. How could such a conversion function look like?

Comment: @SteffenRoeber: What other types? aggregates, enums, pointers... all of them? Neutral type must be something like a class to admit as constructor for every type you want to support and a conversion function to every type you want to support.